# How use maven profile propertied in project config.properties

Tags: java, maven, properties, pom.xml

I'd use different environments to run testng tests. In pom.xml I specified my profiles like:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <browser.name>firefox</browser.name>
            <site.url>my_url1</site.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>remote</id>
        <properties>
            <browser.name>chrome</browser.name>
            <site.url>my_url2</site.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

In config.properties I set following:

```
browser=${browser.name}
siteUrl=${site.url}
```

In java code I read properties like:

```
    public static String getProp(String name) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(PropertyReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    String value = "";
    if (name != null) {
        value = properties.getProperty(name);
    }
    return value;
}
```

When I try to run tests using `mvn test -Plocal` I got errors because properties are not read correctly and browser is equal "${browser.name}" instead of "firefox". How could I fix this?

Comment: just a guess: try to set the option before the goal: `mvn -Plocal test`

Comment: Did you filter your config.properties? Where is this file located?

Comment: You need to [activate filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Comment: thanks filtering helped